# Matching array value (PHP Array)

Tags: php, arrays

Input post :

```
$_POST['dateSlot']
$_POST['timeStart']
$_POST['timeEnd']
$_POST['quota']
```

These input post will resulting the below array.

```
Array
(
    [dateSlot] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-04-05
            [1] => 2018-04-05
            [2] => 2018-04-05
        )

    [timeStart] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:06 AM
            [1] => 10:06 AM
            [2] => 9:06 AM
        )

    [timeEnd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:06 AM
            [1] => 9:06 AM
            [2] => 7:06 AM
        )

    [quota] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
        )
)
```

I'm trying to foreach them to match the index key and form another array with this idea. Not so sure if can get the value I want :

```
foreach ($_POST['dateSlot'] as $k => $val) {
    foreach ($_POST['timeStart'] as $k2 => $val2) {
        foreach ($_POST['timeEnd'] as $k3 => $val3) {
            foreach ($_POST['quota'] as $k4 => $val4) {
                if($k == $k2 && $k == $k3 && $k == $k4){
                    $timeslots[$k]['date_slot'] = $val;
                    $timeslots[$k]['time_start'] = $val2;
                    $timeslots[$k]['time_end'] = $val3;
                    $timeslots[$k]['event_quota'] = $val4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By that foreach, I'm getting the error **Illegal string offset** for `date_slot`, `time_start`, `time_end`, and `event_quota`

Based on the rows in the array, my goal is to re-form the array so that they all will be combined together to form 3 rows.

Example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_slot]   => 2018-04-05
            [time_start]  => 11:06 AM
            [time_end]    => 11:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_slot]   => 2018-04-05
            [time_start]  => 10:06 AM
            [time_end]    => 9:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_slot]   => 2018-04-05
            [time_start]  => 9:06 AM
            [time_end]    => 7:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 10
        )
)
```

Comment: Do your input field names look like this? `name="dateSlot[]"` it would be better if they looked like this `name="row[0][dateSlot]"`where `0` is how you group each data set.

Comment: Yes my input field is like `name="dateSlot[]"`

Comment: Will your form have any checkbox inputs? if so I'd strongly suggest not using that notation, you will run into trouble as an unchecked checkbox won't return a presence in the post data, and your array alignment will be inconsistent.

Comment: All my input control using the `text`. No checkbox

Comment: Perfect, you won't run into any issues then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the element keys in all 4 of those post variables will always correlate to one timeslot element, then I think this will work for you:

```
foreach ($_POST['dateSlot'] as $key => $value) {
    $timeslots[$key] = [
        'date_slot'   => $_POST['dateSlot'][$key],
        'time_start'  => $_POST['timeStart'][$key],
        'time_end'    => $_POST['timeEnd'][$key],
        'event_quota' => $_POST['quota'][$key],
    ];
}

print_r($timeslots);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to grouping this kind of data without needing to know the key names in advance.

This works by using the first row's data `current( $data )` as the main iterator, then builds an array by combining the outer keys `array_keys( $data )` and the inner column value `array_column( $data, $column )` with `array_combine()` which combines two arrays of keys and an array of value to make each row's final array structure keyed by column name.

***This is absolutely reliant on each multidimensional array having the same count of elements.*** As such this is not suitable for forms with checkbox inputs in them. At which point I would suggest using `name="row[0][ColumnName]"` as your name attribute and negating the need for this array processing.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

---

```
$data = array(
  'Column-1'=>array('Row-1a','Row-2a','Row-3a'),
  'Column-2'=>array('Row-1b','Row-2b','Row-3b'),
  'Column-3'=>array('Row-1c','Row-2c','Row-3c')
);

$array = array();

foreach( array_keys( current( $data ) ) as $column )
{
  $array[] = array_combine( array_keys( $data ), array_column( $data, $column ) );
}

print_r( $array );
```

Produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Column-1] => Row-1a
            [Column-2] => Row-1b
            [Column-3] => Row-1c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Column-1] => Row-2a
            [Column-2] => Row-2b
            [Column-3] => Row-2c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Column-1] => Row-3a
            [Column-2] => Row-3b
            [Column-3] => Row-3c
        )

)
```

Comment: Nice answer...Can you please explain?

Comment: @GYaN I've attempted to add a bit of an explanation :)

Comment: `array_combine` teamed up with `array_column` is the powerhouse of this approach

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateSlot = $_POST['dateSlot']
$timeStart = $_POST['timeStart']
$timeEnd = $_POST['timeEnd']
$quota = $_POST['quota']

$all = array();

foreach($dateSlot as $key => $date) {
    $all[] = array(
       "data_slot" => $dateSlot[$key],
       "time_start" => $timeStart[$key],
       "time_end" => $timeEnd[$key],
       "quota"    => $quota[$key]
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$array = array(
            'dateSlot' => array('2018-04-05','2018-04-05','2018-04-05'),
            'timeStart' => array('11:06 AM','10:06 AM','9:06 AM'),
            'timeEnd' => array('11:06 AM','9:06 AM','7:06 AM'),
            'quota' => array(12,10,10)
        );
```

**Solution**

```
$new = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array['dateSlot']);$i++){
    $new[] = array(
        'dateSlot' => $array['dateSlot'][$i],
        'timeStart' => $array['timeStart'][$i],
        'timeEnd' => $array['timeEnd'][$i],
        'event_quota' => $array['quota'][$i],
    );
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dateSlot] => 2018-04-05
            [timeStart] => 11:06 AM
            [timeEnd] => 11:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dateSlot] => 2018-04-05
            [timeStart] => 10:06 AM
            [timeEnd] => 9:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dateSlot] => 2018-04-05
            [timeStart] => 9:06 AM
            [timeEnd] => 7:06 AM
            [event_quota] => 10
        )

)
```